# QnA Maker with cards

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker, adaptive-cards

I want to add cards in my QnA Maker. I my QnA maker if anyone asks about "what services we provide?" Bot should answer (for example: We provide following services /n/n 1: Bot Development /n/n 2: Web Development /n/n 3: Documentation). In this example bot should reply it with the card and if user clicks on any of the above mentioned services than it should gives details about that.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you using v3 or v4, and are you using node or c#?

Comment: i am using c#, could you please guide me with both v3 and v4?

Comment: Working on crafting an example

Answer (score 2):

QnA Maker has just released a new feature called [multi-turn conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation) whcih does exactly what you are looking for.

Once you have added some multi-turn conversations to your knowledge base you can try this out by downloading the [BotBuilder-Samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) and opening the [qnamaker-prompting sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting) (C# and NodeJS provided) then you can plug your knowledge base details into the `appsettings.json` (C#) or `.env` (NodeJS) file and test the functionality locally using the Bot Framework Emulator.

The key part is [this method](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore/Dialogs/QnADialog.cs#L24-L50) which checks to see if the result contains any prompts and returns the response accordingly - it is called inside the [controller](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/qnamaker-prompting/csharp_dotnetcore/Controllers/BotController.cs#L32).

This should give you a good idea of how to get started.